# best system for rviz, gazebo

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm planning to buy a laptop. But i'm not sure which model of laptop should i buy. Can any one suggest me which is the best laptop or what specs are best to run the gazebo, rviz, rqt etc on the pc? I want to run all of them in single instance i.e in one window rviz, in another gazebo and in another rqt related plugins.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362715/best-system-for-rviz,-gazebo/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2020-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To run gazebo smooth  with multi sensor you have to have the fastest cpu and gpu possible. The other Programms do not use that mutch resources. Then the questen is what is the best cpu gpu for your robot application.

So a modern game or if you have the money workstation notebook will be good.

The graphics schuld be more nvidia then AMD because cude is often used then openCL

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2020-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0